# How do you get the POST request object or URL string in Play Framework's WS API?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

In WS.url(url).post(Map("key" -> Seq("value"))) is there a way to see the actual request and that’s made and not just the response?

Do I have to use something like wireshark?

Answer (score -1):

WS is actually where you defined request, underlying request object is more implementation details. What would you like to see?